# Angular.js, how to check authentication service in controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication

In angular.js, on all controllers that require authentication I am doing the following:

```
function controller($state, $rootScope, $scope, oAuthService) {
    //oAuthService is a custom service
    if(!oAuthService.isAuthorized()) {
         $state.go('401');
    }
    ...
}
```

The problem is two fold. First, I don't like that I have to copy and paste these 3 lines into the top of every controller that requires auth. Second, if you transition to another controller authentication is not checked *(only check when the page is hard refreshed)*. What is the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add below lines of code in your root controller..

```
    $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function (event, oAuthService) {
        if(!oAuthService.isAuthorized()) {
                   $state.go('401');
                   event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**

to answer your comment.

you should set some boolean property on each state indicating whether auth is needed.

```
   .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: 'partial-home.html',
        isSecured: true
    })
```

and then

```
    $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function (event, toState) {
        if(!oAuthService.isAuthorized() && toState.isSecured && toState.name != '401') {
                   $state.go('401');
                   event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the controller/page does not require authentication? How is that handled?

Comment: When I add `$state.go('401');` in the `if(!oAuthService.isAuthorized()) {` block Angular is crashing with `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`.

Comment: add a check `toState.name != '401'`

Comment: Never-mind, you are right, adding a property to each state in the router `requiresAuth` worked like a champ. Thanks so much!